# Wrapping a C function that expect C dynamic callbacks

Tags: python, python-c-api, cpython

I am trying to write a wrapper around libedit (a BSD alternative to readline with a slightly different API) and there is a way to add a named function to the C API.

For example in C:

```
static unsigned char show_help(EditLine *e, int ch) {
    printf("Help");
}

el = el_init(argv[0], stdin, stdout, stderr);
el_set(el, EL_ADDFN, "help",  "This is help", show_help);
el_set(el, EL_BIND, "\?", "help", NULL);
```

I call el_set to add a function and then bind that function later on.

I can't find a good way to allow me to wrap EL_ADDFN to bind Python methods dynamically.  I could create a bunch of prenamed C function and wrap them all individually to python methods, but I would rather like emulate the C API as closely as possible.

Is there a way to call EL_ADDFN and determine which python method it is calling?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  One single handler function (which I'll describe below).  Wrap EL_ADDFN so that it records the mapping of name to python function, but always uses the one handler function.  Wrap EL_BIND, so that it records the mapping of character to function name.  Your handler function should look up the ch parameter in your character to name mapping and then lookup the name to function mapping and then call the function.  (If ADDFN must be called before BIND, you could create a map of ch to function and populate that directly in the the BIND wrapper.)

In pseudo C:

```
const char *chmap[256];  // initialize to zero
struct hashtable *namemap;  // up to you to find a
                            // hashtable implementation that
                            // will take const char * and map to
                            // PyObject * (function object);

static unsigned char python_func(EditLine *e, int ch) {
    const char *name = chmap[ch];
    // check for errors
    PyObject *func = lookup(namemap, name);
    // check for errors

    PyObject *editline = convert(e); // or whatever you have
    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(func, NULL);
    // check result, convert to unsigned char, and return
}
```

So, ADDFN wrapper populates the hashtable, and the BIND operator populates the chmap.